# FirestoreRecyclerAdapter how do I get the key

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

With new firestore how do I get the key (document ID) from adapter?

With Firebase Database we get this with

```
String key = this.getRef(position).getKey();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Was just having the same problem.  This works for me.  FirestoreUI version 3.1.0.

Within your onBindViewHolder, (and note you will need to make "position" final):

```
                        String docId = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();

                        Log.d("GETREFTEST", docId);
```

Happy coding.

Comment: It's working even from inside the adapter FirestoreRecyclerAdapter

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` from FirebaseUI, you can get the ID for the document at `position` using the following snippet:

```
String id = getSnapshots().get(position).getId()
```

Comment: There is no such a method.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one I got using this

> intent.putExtra(Activity.KEY_ID, model.getId());

activity = replace with your own activity and

model = replace with your own model